# Connection unit testing in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest, mysql-connector-python, python-unittest.mock

I am new to Python unit testing and I am not sure how i can create a unit test of this function that returns a connection?

```
def connection(self):
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', 
                     database='test',
                     user='user', 
                     password='password',
                     auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
    return connection
```

Comment: What's the point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could mock out `mysql.connector.connect` and ensure that it's called, but honestly this is probably too small a *unit* to provide any benefits to your unit tests. This is just delegating a call to `mysql.connector.connect`, which itself should be tested (by the `mysql` package).

```
class TestConnection(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.mock('module_under_test.mysql.connector.connect')
    def test_connection(self, mockconnect):
        module_under_test.connection()
        mockconnect.assert_called()
```

I suppose you could also check to make sure that it always returns *something* (to keep from future revisions forgetting to `return` out of the function.

```
    # inside test_connection as above
        connection = module_under_test.connection()
        self.assertIsNotNone(connection)
        mockconnect.assert_called()
```

Comment: This provides no value whatsoever. What matters given (limited) context is what the function returns, not how it creates it. To me this test is a clear violation of encapsulation. In fact, a function that calls `connect` then returns `42` will pass that test, while a function that returns a proper connection through another mean will fail it.

Comment: @spectras I agree and mentioned as much in the answer, though I'm not sure how it's a clear violation of encapsulation.

Comment: It looks at the inside implementation of `connection()`. Assuming the point of `connection()` is to encapsulate the details of creating a connection, encapsulation is broken. To be fair, to make a proper test we should have the documentation of the function. If it says *“invoke mysql.connector.connect”* then fair enough. But if it just says *“create a connection”*, that's what should be tested: that it returns a proper connection (`isinstance` of a specific class, a `cursor` method can be called on returned object…). *How* it creates it is irrelevant, unless part of the contract.

Comment: @spectras that's a fair assessment. Without a better idea of what `connection` does it's tough to advise further, however :(. if `connection` took a path to `host`, it would be easier to mock out (you could mock a sql database with some test data in your `setUp`, then open a connection to it and do some stuff with the cursor, asserting its results.

Comment: Agreed, as is, the function is not well defined and lacks instrumentation to be testable in a really useful way.

Comment: What is the import for @unittest.mock?

Comment: @Banik `import unittest.mock`

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this for a custom class I created that wraps the Oracle MySQL Connector for Python. I would do something like the following:

```py
import unittest
import mysql.connector

class TestConnection(unittest.TestCase):
    """Oracle MySQL for Python Connector tests."""

    connection = None

    def setUp(self):
        config = {
            user = 'user',
            password = 'password',
            host = 'localhost',
            database = 'test',
            auth_plugin = 'mysql_native_password'
        }
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.connection is not None and self.connection.is_connected():
            self.connection.close()

    def test_connection(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.connection.is_connected())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This solution is based on the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods provided by `unittest` that are executed before and after each test, respectively. This allows us to connect to the database, run a simple connection test, then close the connection. This ensures that there are no hanging connections after the completion of unit tests.